# Modal popover not showing image

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, popover

The task is to insert a simple modal popover as an alert for clients to be notified of a temporary relocation. On page load, a transparent background appears but the image nor the close button appears.

DATA

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="../js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="../js/popover.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>

<style>
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalContent {
    width: 750px;
    z-index: 10000;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: none;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient;
    background: -o-linear-gradient;
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
</style>
```

CODE

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
<div class="modalDialog">
<div class="modalContent">
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
<img src="image.jpg" width="750px"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This seems like a fairly straightforward task but I cannot seem to resolve this issue by multiple attempts. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea about popover plugin, but i have created fiddle for this using bootstrap plugin, when the page gets opened modal will be appear with some content (You can replace it by your content).

Sample HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

And JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasbLpjo/1/)

Note:  I did not included popover.js.

Comment: Thank you for this, it works 100%. I suppose I was making things more difficult with the addition of the popover.js. Cheers.

Comment: After implementing your code onto a specific page, I seem to be having a jquery conflict. Once live, the main slider on this page doesn't appear. Is there a specific jquery file for modal which will not conflict with the flexslider?

Comment: can you please post the code of that page in fiddle, so that i can fix that.